# Get specific URL with PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

So for my code I basically need to get a specific URL from a webpage, I use Simple HTML DOM Parser, so far I managed to get all the links from the webpage with the class `.linkify`, which results in having 18 different links, and I will need to have only the second one in a variable.

Here's my code:

```
$html = file_get_html("http://saucenao.com/search.php?db=999&url=http://simg4.gelbooru.com//images/4f/3d/$file");
foreach($html->find('a.linkify') as $element)

echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

How do I make it so it only generates the second link?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can select which one you want by modifying

`$html->find('a.linkify')`

to

`$html->find('a.linkify', 1)`

To fetch the 2nd one, we use `,1`. It's index based so we start at 0 (0 = First one, 1 = Second one)

To get the `href` in a single line, do the following:

`$html->find('a.linkify', 1)->href`

Comment: So I just did what you said and it seems like nothing appears on the page, no error code, just a blank page. Here's my code:
`$html = file_get_html("http://saucenao.com/search.php?db=999&url=http://simg4.gelbooru.com//images/4f/3d/$file");
foreach($html->find('a.linkify', 1) as $element)

echo $element->href . '<br>';`